# Resize a File in Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I resize a file from the command prompt (or in a batch file)?

- It needs to treat the file as **binary**. *The file format is irrelevant and arbitrary.*
- Extending the file should pad it with zeros.
- Shrinking the file should truncate the file.

In other words:

How do you duplicate the functionality of [**`SetEndOfFile`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx) in the command prompt?

Comment: You could try [diskpart](http://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/images/diskpart-resize-partition-3889/diskpart-extend-volume.gif).

Comment: To extend the file, do you want to pad it with zeros (ASCII) or nulls (bytes)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe the functionality exists natively in the DOS shell, I suspect you need to use another program to get the job done.  Here are a few possibilities:

1. There is a tool called [Trunc](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Trunc.shtml) which claims to do exactly what you are after:

> Trunc is a Windows command-line app to truncate files to a specified size. Also usable to enlarge a file.

You'll have to try it out to find out exactly how the file is getting padded out (e.g. with zeros or garbage) but otherwise this seems to fit the bill of what you are asking for.

2. [fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil) is a Windows XP and above system tool that appears to have some functionality that might help.  Specifically the [`fsutil file`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file) subcommand appears to be able to create, set length and also zero fill files.

Specifically:

```
fsutil file createnew "C:\temp\myfile" 1024
```

Will create a zero filled 1024 byte file.

To change the size of an existing file:

```
fsutil file seteof filename length
```

3. [UVHD](http://uvsoftware.ca/uvhd.htm#2H19) is a hex editor that appears to have the functions you are asking for.  The only problem is that it only works under Windows/SFU (Services for Unix) and not DOS.  What that actually means to an end user I don't actually know, but I have a vague suspicion that SFU was dropped in Vista and Win 7.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks, `trunc` does what I need.
Oh, and a note: SFU (or rather, SUA -- "Subsystem for Unix-Based Applications", aka Interix) wasn't dropped in Windows 7; it's just now an *optional* component in the Ultimate version, unfortuntately. :\

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I couldn't find much in the way of information on SUA/SFU though to be honest I didn't look too closely.  I've also found another way to create arbitrary length files using `fsutil` and edited my answer, but as I noted I cannot see a valid way to truncate the files.

Comment: By the way, I thought I'd point something out: I believe the valid data length is the *virtual* length of the file on the disk, not the *physical* length. If the file is compressed, for example, it could actually be smaller -- you'd need the compressed size of the file.

Comment: But fsutil *does* have a command to set the EOF, `fsutil file seteof filename length`, I checked and this works as expected (I found this on https://ss64.com/nt/fsutil.html)

Comment: @lukeuser I suspect that when this answer was written 9 years ago the command may not have existed. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file seems to suggest that there is something in the `fsutil file` has some applicability only to Windows 8 and above. I know it existed in Win7, but I do not remember seeing that particular command when I researched this all those years back.

Comment: @Mokubai Ah, that didn't really occur to me, but it makes sense. The past is a foreign country; they do things differently there.

Comment: @lukeuser But `fsutil file seteof` command is available in Windows 10 Version 1607 (OS build 14393) or later.

Comment: On https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file it says "Applies to: Windows Server 2022, Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016, Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8"  so its been around at least that long, but not when this answer was written.  @Mokubai maybe update this answer at the top to refer to the other answer for Win8 and above? That would help a lot of people out.

Answer (score 9):

To set "`SetEndOfFile` in the command prompt":

```
FSUTIL file seteof <filename> <truncated size>
```

To increase (existing)file size (padding nulls):

```
FSUTIL file seteof <filename> <new size>
```

Works at file system level, much faster than copying required file contents into a new file.

Answer (score 5):

```
copy /Y nul: file.txt
```

For setting to 0 bytes only, of course.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: +1 I agree that it's not the right answer but it's exactly what I came here looking for - how to truncate a file from the Windows command line.

Answer (score 2):

try [my BSD truncate build for Windows](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/builds/truncate-1.12-win32.zip).

EDIT: it is not working with files >2GB.

Alternatives that works well with big files:

- trunc.exe ([previously on google code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/trunc/), [now mirrored in softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Trunc.shtml))
- [chsize32](http://www.ltr-data.se/files/chsize32.zip) (closed source)

Answer (score 2):

If you have GnuWin32 installed, then you can use `dd` to do it.

```
dd if=nul of=/the/file/to/truncate bs=1 count=0 seek=the_file_size oflag=append
```

Comment: dd potential never ceases to amaze me, command works but without if=nul.